# numpy.select has a strange behavior

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I have some troubles with np.select:

```
s=np.array([False,True],dtype=bool)
v=np.array([np.array([1,2]),np.array([3])])
np.select(s,v)
```

return

```
array([3, 3])
```

which is not clear for me. Moreover, if I replace `v` by

```
v=np.array([np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4,5])])
```

I get an error. This is clearly due to the variable type of `v` since it works well when `v` is an array of integers or an array of arrays with similar length (a matrix). So why does not it work in my case ? I am looking for a nice method to solve it (without a for loop).

(I want to use this kind of code with `contours` and `hierarchy` (`cv.findContours` outputs) and I have isolated the difficulty above. Unfortunately, each contours does not have the same length...)

Answer (score 0):

`np.select` docs talks about the 2 arguments being lists.  If they are arrays they are treated as lists, iterating on the first dimension.

```
In [112]: np.select([False,True],[np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,3])])            
Out[112]: array([3, 3])
```

Evidently if the arrays inside the lists differ in shape, it tries to broadcast them together.  In this case the common broadcast shape is (2,).  So the boolean condition is expanded:

```
[False,True]
[np.array([False,False]),np.array([True,True])]
```

Likewise your first example the `np.array([3])` broadcasts to the (2,) I use above.

```
In [113]: np.select([False,True],[np.array([1,2]), np.array([3])])              
Out[113]: array([3, 3])
```

But when one of the arrays has shape (3,) that broadcasting is no longer possible:

```
In [114]: np.select([False,True],[np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4,5])])          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in select(condlist, choicelist, default)
    699     # for example when all choices are scalars.
    700     condlist = np.broadcast_arrays(*condlist)
--> 701     choicelist = np.broadcast_arrays(*choicelist)
    702 
    703     # If cond array is not an ndarray in boolean format or scalar bool, abort.
    ....
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

In short, `condlist` and `choicelist` must be equal lengths, and all elements of those lists must be arrays that can broadcast with each other. The output will be an array with that common broadcasting shape.

`np.select` is not widely used.  And I suspect that in your case with ragged, non broadcastable arrays, it is not useful.

Comment: Thanks for this argued answer. I finally used a for loop (!):

    h=[]
    for k, b in enumerate(s):
        if b:
            h.append(v[k])

It is not very nice. I do not understand why when the arrays inside the lists differ in shape, np.select tries to broadcast them together.